# Django - several form instances or several object instances

Tags: python, django, forms

I am creating a web app With Django for summarizing things. The layout that I am working on should look like this:

```
Form to edit the first Topic name
topic.date
topic.time
Form to edit the first topic summary
```

---

```
Form to edit the second Topic name
topic.date
topic.time
Form to edit the second topic summary
```

---

etc. etc

The thing is that I am not sure how to create several form instances in several object instances.. The only way to display form that I know is by using a pk (instance = Topic.objects.get(pk=1)) and that does not work for me because several objects with a form (to edit each one them) must be displayed on a page...

I am displaying my objects in the template simply using a for loop.

ModelForms does not work for me as well because I dont know how should I access model's data (topic.date) when looping over the form + I will need several model forms (Topic and summary are several models).

My models:

```
class Topic(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class Summary(models.Model):
    content = models.TextField(max_length=1000)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.content
```

Comment: What You need is Formset. Just check django documentation.

Comment: **Bibhas** > thank you for the answer, but formset uses for loop and I am already displaying my objects in a for loop (this is how  can  access lecture.date and list all objects)

Comment: Not sure what you mean. But Formset creates a single form that can contain days of multiple objects. And you can save it once and all the objects are created/updated. You can even handle the form saving yourself.

Comment: **Bibhas** > I meant that as far as I know when displaying a formset you need to **for** loop over it in the template. And I need do display additional data from my model near the formset's form (like **lecture.date** which is 'models.DateTimeField'). Then its like for loop in a for loop... Is there any way to achieve this ?

Comment: Did you try searching for that answer first? If you create a modelformset, you can access `{{form.instance.fieldname}}`.

Comment: **Bibhas** > Thank you, I haven't heard about {{form.instance.fieldname}} although I have read about formsets. But is there any way to display a formset thats based on two models ? As I have mentioned, Topic and Summary are separate models..

Comment: Sorry, but there isn't enough information to debug your problem. And sounds like most of your problem is due to lack of research. I suggest you search more about your problem and find the smallest possible trouble and post the error, traceback and the related code here so that others can help you.